# VBA formula removing everything after second space

Tags: excel, vba

I was trying to copy from column D to column E first two words of each row but still can not find where the error is....

```
Range("E1:E" & lLastRow).Formula = "=LEFT(D1,FIND("" "",D1,FIND("" "",D1)+1)-1)"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option, instead of using a Formula, you can use the `Split` function.

***Code***

```
Dim i As Long, LastRow As Long
Dim WordsArr As Variant

' loop through rows
For i = 1 To LastRow
    WordsArr = Split(Range("D" & i).Value, " ")  ' use Split and space to read cell words to array

    If UBound(WordsArr) >= 1 Then ' make sure the cell contents is at least 2 words
        Range("E" & i).Value = WordsArr(0) & " " & WordsArr(1) ' insert only the first 2 words

    Else ' in case there are less than 2 words
        ' do someting....

    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead ...

```
Range("E1:E" & lLastRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=LEFT(RC[-1],FIND("" "",RC[-1],FIND("" "",RC[-1])+1)-1)"
```

I find using R1C1 better for those sort of operations, especially given you want your references to be dynamic, not absolute.

Alternatively, add the formula you had normally and simply fill down.

Comment: I think there is an error in formula , instead of first two words from column D I am still getting formula in the column E....     =LEFT(RC[-1],FIND(" ",RC[-1],FIND(" ",RC[-1])+1)-1)

Comment: Is your cell formatted as text? If so, format it as general.

Comment: The only reason for a cell to accept an equals sign as the first character and NOT treat it as a formula is if the cell format is set to text or there is a leading apostrophe.